# Disable GNOME sushi / quick previewer

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gnome-sushi

Can someone please explain how to disable this quick preview feature?

Answer (score 1):

Note that GNOME sushi is not pre-installed by default in any of the Ubuntu releases and it's available from the 'universe' repo.

To disable it, simply remove the `gnome-sushi` package by running the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-sushi
```

Comment: When I try that apt also tries to remove gnome-core.

Comment: So that's how you got sushi installed, it came as a dependency of `gnome-core` (as I mentioned in the answer it should not be pre-installed by default). In that case there is no clean way to remove sushi without removing `gnome-core` as it depends on sushi. But then again `gnome-core` is just a metapackage, *for all intents and purposes* removing it won't have any effect on the system.

Comment: Thanks that did it. gnome-core sounded important and so I was hesitant to proceed (!)